# My service implementation is not seen by Liferay, despite high service.ranking

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, gogo-shell

I wrote a module that contains this implementation of the [com.liferay.portal.security.audit.AuditMessageProcessor](https://docs.liferay.com/ce/apps/foundation/latest/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/security/audit/AuditMessageProcessor.html) service:

```
@Component(
    configurationPid = "my.MyAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration",
    immediate = true,
    property = {
            "eventTypes=*",
            "service.ranking:Integer=100000"
    },
    service = AuditMessageProcessor.class
)
public class MyElasticsearchAuditMessageProcessor
        implements AuditMessageProcessor {

    @Override
    public void process(AuditMessage auditMessage) {
        _log.info("This never appears even after login/logout");
        elasticsearch.send(auditMessage);
    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        _myAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration = ConfigurableUtil
            .createConfigurable(
                MyAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration.class, properties);
    }

    @Reference(unbind = "-")
    protected my.Elasticsearch elasticsearch;

    private static final Log _log =
        LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyAuditMessageProcessor.class);

    private volatile MyAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration
        _myAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration;
}
```

Elasticsearch.java:

```
@Component(
        immediate = true
    )
public class Elasticsearch {
    [...]
}
```

After deploying, my module is seen by Gogo Shell as not implementing that service, as seen below. The other two services that my module implements are visible though.

```
g! inspect capability service 548
myaudit_1.0.0 [548] provides:
---------------------------------
service; javax.servlet.Filter with properties:
   servlet-filter-name = Audit Download Filter
   url-pattern = /documents/*
   servlet-context-name = 
   component.name = my.DownloadFilter
   component.id = 2573
   service.id = 7181
   service.bundleid = 548
   service.scope = bundle
   Used by:
      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.200.v20150831-0856 [0]
service; com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCRenderCommand with properties:
   service.ranking = 100
   mvc.command.name = /document_library/view_file_entry
   javax.portlet.name = com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet, com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLAdminPortlet, com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_IGDisplayPortlet
   component.name = my.MyViewFileEntryMVCRenderCommand
   component.id = 2576
   service.id = 7182
   service.bundleid = 548
   service.scope = bundle
   Used by:
      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.200.v20150831-0856 [0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

For info, inside my module's jar this `OSGI-INF/my.MyAuditMessageProcessor.xml` exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.3.0" name="my.MyAuditMessageProcessor" immediate="true" activate="activate" modified="activate" configuration-pid="my.MyAuditMessageProcessorConfiguration">
  <implementation class="my.MyAuditMessageProcessor"/>
  <service>
    <provide interface="com.liferay.portal.security.audit.AuditMessageProcessor"/>
  </service>
  <property name="eventTypes" type="String" value="*"/>
  <property name="service.ranking" type="Integer" value="100000"/>
</scr:component>
```

Comment: Can you check if your jar contains the DS xml for your service?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: Added, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you try the scr shell commands to see if your component has some unsatisfied requirements?

Comment: Are you using DXP or Liferay Portal 7 CE? Keep in mind audit is DXP only feature.

Comment: @MilenDyankov: Yes, I am on DXP.

Answer (score 3):

As tipped by Christian, the problem is that my **component** had unsatisfied requirements. Please note that it is different from a bundle missing requirements, it is a level below.

My bundle has all requirements satisfied, but my module was missing a requirement. Here is how I found it out:

1. Start Gogo Shell
2. Type `scr:list`
3. Luckily, your components should be towards the end of the long list
4. That gives you your component's id, for instance 2587
5. Type `scr:info 2587`
6. That will display `UnsatisfiedReference` and `Target: null` for the missing dependency

In my case, I was trying to @Reference a @Component directly rather than a service. I solved the problem by creating an ElasticsearchService interface and making the Elasticsearch component implement it.

Comment: Great you found it .. but what was actually missing? In the code you showed there should be no possibility for a missing reference?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: Sorry I had overlooked a part of the code, I updated the question and answer.

Comment: Saw it. Yes .. unsatisfied mandatory references are a typical cause why a service is not present.